# How to add/delete an index in a multi index dataframe Python

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, multi-index

I have a multi-index dataframe where I'd like to add a "three" index with 6 values, 2 for a, b and c in columns X and Y.

```
 import pandas as pd, numpy as np

 np.arrays = [["one", "one", "one", "two", "two", "two"], ["a", "b", "c", "a", "b", "c"]]

 df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randn(6,2), 
              index = pd.MultiIndex.from_tuples(list(zip(*np.arrays))),
             columns = ["X", "Y"])
 df = round(abs(df), 3)
 df

              X     Y
one     a   1.521   0.048
        b   1.595   1.783
        c   0.286   1.042
two     a   1.480   1.071
        b   0.807   1.058
        c   1.730   1.233
```

What I'd like is:

```
                 X     Y
    one     a   1.521   0.048
            b   1.595   1.783
            c   0.286   1.042
    two     a   1.480   1.071
            b   0.807   1.058
            c   1.730   1.233
    three   a   1.2     5.5
            b   4.2     2.2
            c   7.8     3.4
```

Also, how do I delete an index? I tried the following code, but it gave an AttributeError: **delitem**

```
del df.loc["one"]
```

Any help would be awesome.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One approach using pd.concat i.e

```
idx = pd.MultiIndex.from_tuples(list(zip(['three']*3,list('abc'))))
new = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randn(3,2), index=idx, columns= df.columns)
new_df = pd.concat([df,new])

                X         Y
one   a  0.270000  0.299000
      b  0.644000  0.073000
      c  1.224000  0.656000
two   a  0.202000  0.097000
      b  2.750000  0.373000
      c  0.421000  0.939000
three a  1.392999 -0.870480
      b -1.899386 -0.249068
      c -0.609149  0.164459
```

And for deleting use drop i.e

```
new_df = new_df.drop('one',level=0)
```

Comment: Thanks Bharath, that definitely works, but I was hoping for something more simple that possibly involved `df.loc["one"].values`. The simpler, the better. Still, definitely appreciate this solution tho.